# Vertical error shading in tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following figure in Tikz (see the MWE below). I have an equation for the line. I have generated the error by plotting the same equation but by changing the `line width`. However, on the RHS of the figure, this ends with the error bar having a non-vertical cut-off. How can this be corrected for?

There is a related topic addressed in [this post](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/error-intervals/). However, I have not managed to find a work-around. Any suggestions?

[image: error]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\definecolor{RoyalAzure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}  

\newcommand\randompath[2]{%
\pgfmathsetseed{#1}%
\addplot[#2,domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth] {0.02*(x+0.2)^(-0.4) -0.19 + (x+0.2)+rand*(x+0.32)*(1-(x+0.2))};%
}


\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/layers/mylayer/.define layer set=
{axis background,axis grid,main,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,axis descriptions,axis foreground}
{/pgfplots/layers/standard}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{set layers=mylayer}%
    \pgfplotsset{/dummy/workaround/.style={/pgfplots/axis on top}}

    \begin{axis}[width=\columnwidth,
        height=0.618\columnwidth,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style={line width=1pt},
        /dummy/workaround,
        xlabel style = {font=\Large, xshift=31ex,yshift=2.5ex},
        ylabel style = {font=\Large, rotate = -90, xshift=3.5ex, yshift=15.5ex},
        xlabel={$\theta$},
        ylabel={$\langle M\rangle$},    
        xmin=0, 
        xmax=1, 
        ymin=0, 
        ymax=1, 
        ticks=none,
        ]
    \randompath{19.2}{RoyalAzure!10!white, line width=14pt}  % ERROR FUNCTION
    \randompath{19.2}{RoyalAzure, line width=1pt}  % ACTUAL FUNCTION
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize in advance if I destroyed too much of your settings. All I am proposing here is to

1. store the random function via `declare function` and
2. use `fillbetween` to shade the area between two functions which emerge from the original one by adding or subtracting some constant.

Why did I mess around with your settings? The way you set the layers seems to be inconsistent with `fillbetween`. Once I removed the layers, other things went berserk, so I just removed these things. (Sorry!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\definecolor{RoyalAzure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={% step 1 : define random function
myf(\x)=0.02*(\x+0.2)^(-0.4) -0.19 + (\x+0.2)+rand*(\x+0.32)*(1-(\x+0.2));}]
    %\pgfplotsset{set layers=mylayer}%
    \pgfplotsset{/dummy/workaround/.style={/pgfplots/axis on top}}

    \begin{axis}[width=\columnwidth,
        height=0.618\columnwidth,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style={line width=1pt},
        /dummy/workaround,
        xlabel style = {font=\Large},
        ylabel style = {font=\Large},
        xlabel={$\theta$},
        ylabel={$\langle M\rangle$},    
        xmin=0, 
        xmax=1, 
        ymin=-1, 
        ymax=2.5, 
        ticks=none,
        ]
    \pgfmathsetseed{2}%
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth,opacity=0,name path=A] {myf(x)+0.15};
    \pgfmathsetseed{2}%
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth,opacity=0,name path=B] {myf(x)-0.15};
    \addplot[RoyalAzure!10!white]  fill between [of=A and B];
    \pgfmathsetseed{2}%
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth,RoyalAzure] {myf(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, I couldn't get the `fillbetween` to work. When I compile this, I still get the axes placement in front of the `addplot`, which is also what I wanted.

Comment: Also, thanks for explaining your posts. I find it incredibly helpful to understand your wizardry :)